# Разметка в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Двигается кнопка, если расширяется лэйбл. Может, ее можно как-то закрепить/заблокировать?

```
self.but_OK = Button(root, background="#555",  text='^Generate our sets^', font='Arial 12', height=3, command=self.generABC)
self.but_OK.grid(column=2, row=5, columnspan=4)
self.res = Label(root,height=6, text='D = ( (A \ B) | (B & A) ) \ (C | B) = {}\n'.format(initeq.initial_eq(self.A,self.B,self.C)), font='Arial 12 bold', bg='white')
self.res.grid(column=1, row=15, sticky=S)
```

Получается, когда результат D очень большой(а это множество), то моя кнопка сдвигается вправо.

Comment: Смотря какой менеджер компоновки у вас используется и как. Вы бы код показали.

Comment: поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи `.pack` можно привязать виджет к определенной стороне `left, right, top, bottom`

Пример:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
label_left = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label left')
label_left.pack(side="left")

label_top = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label top')
label_top.pack(side="top")

label_right = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label right')
label_right.pack(side="right")

label_bottom = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label bottom')
label_bottom.pack(side="bottom")
root.mainloop()
```

---

Так же можно при помощи `.place(x=, y=)` можно зафискировать на определенной оси `x, y`
Пример:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
label_left = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label left')
label_left.place(x=0, y=0)

label_top = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label top')
label_top.place(x=0, y=50)

label_right = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label right')
label_right.place(x=0, y=100)

label_bottom = tkinter.Label(root, text='Label bottom')
label_bottom.place(x=0, y=150)
root.mainloop()
```